# how to catch exceptions in eventmachine

Tags: ruby, exception, eventmachine

I'm using eventmachine 1.0.0 with ruby 1.9.3. Now when an exception occurs it's silently ignored. The reactor continues to run, nothing is output. Of course I don't have any custom  `rescue` commands which catch the exception.

This is how I start my reactor. But my `error_handler` never gets called... :-(

```
  EventMachine::run do
    EventMachine.error_handler do |e|
      $stderr.puts "Exception during event: #{e.message} (#{e.class})"
      $stderr.puts (e.backtrace || [])[0..10].join("\n")
    end

    puts "Starting ftp server on port 21"
    EventMachine::start_server("0.0.0.0", 21, self)
  end
```

Comment: I don't know about eventmachine, but probably that kind of things run in subthreads that they create. And errors raised in subthreads are invisible to the main thread unless you make it visible. You need to `rescue` an error inside those threads, and then process the error. Maybe you can try putting `begin` ... `rescue` ... `end` inside `EventMachine.run do` ... `end` and see if you can capture the error there.

Comment: Find something in the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416349/how-do-you-catch-exceptions-in-an-eventmachine-implementation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread on `error_handler` use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventmachine/I9UjAUjMTtM). The event loop terminates if an exception comes through your code. That could be the reason why error_handler` is not being called. It is mainly for communicating C-level errors to Ruby.