# Debugging websocket 1006

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm building a server based on [ruby-websockets-chat-demo](https://github.com/heroku-examples/ruby-websockets-chat-demo) but have extended it to support one-to-one client/server communications across isolated channels.  I have the base server working fine at this point, but I need to continue to develop and extend upon it.

My issue is that, anytime an error occurs within the server, a close with a 1006 is thrown to the client and it simply terminates without any clue as to what happened.  This makes sense in production, I assume, but it causes havoc with development.

I've tried setting my own rescues and traps, but they seem to be just ignored.  Using RubyMine, I can set breakpoints and walk through the code to find where it broke and then identify the issue, but that is a real pain.

I don't know what is trapping the errors, whether it is faye-websocket, eventmachine, or something else, really.  Because it is caught and handled silently, it's very hard to discover.

Is there someway to disable this trap?  Or, what is the best way to debug issues within a faye-websocket based client and server?  Search as I might, I haven't been able to find that information.  Probably just haven't yet hit upon the appropriate search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went back to basic Ruby and inserted this code at the server's "on close" event:

```
if @debug
 puts "MyserverBackend>> Close entered. Last error:#{$!.class}:#{$!.to_s};Module:#{$0};"
 $@.each { |backtrace| puts backtrace }
 exit
end
```

This identifies where the failure is occurring and enhances debugging.  For example, when I forced the error by issuing "xputs" instead of "puts" in the "on message" event, I now receive this clear information:

```
MyserverBackend>> Close entered.  Last error:NoMethodError:undefined method `xputs' for #<Myserver::MyserverBackend:0x4c9b2e8>;Module:.../ruby/bin/rackup;Line:2;
.../projects/myserver/middlewares/myserver_backend.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in call'
.../projects/myserver/middlewares/myserver_backend.rb:43:in `each'
.../projects/myserver/middlewares/myserver_backend.rb:43:in `block in call'
...
```

Before this, my client would just terminate with a 1006 and the server would give me no notice at all of what had happened.  Hope this helps someone else debug those nasty, ubiquitous 1006 errors.

ADDED OPTION:
I found another option.  I execute this method as the very first statement of each WS method such as open/message/close/error.  It is related to EventMachine, running under the covers within faye-websocket.  I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628232/how-to-catch-top-level-failures-on-an-eventmachine-server).

```
def catch_error
  EventMachine.error_handler do |e|
    puts "Catch_error: #{caller[0]}: Last error:#{$!.class}:#{$!.to_s}; Module:#{$0}; Line:#{$.}; Error raised during event loop: Error:#{e.message}" #.red
    raise
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm curious and I hope it's okay that I ask: why not use an existing websocket framework (i.e. Faye / ActionCable / Plezi)? and why use EM Websockets instead of a Rack server that supports websockets such as Iodine? I'm the author of Iodine and Plezi and I'm asking to better understand potential users before the release of the new versions (they're on GitHub).

Comment: @Myst No problem!  Actually, I am using the faye-websocket-ruby gem that uses eventmachine.  I am also using Redis PubSub.  As a whole, the application is highly specialized so out-of-the-box solutions don't really suit it.  I did build an ActionCable app to try it, but the clients are Python-based micro systems that it didn't support.  I looked at Plezi and Iodine, but didn't choose to go there.  After ActionCable, I realized I wanted lower-level control closer to native.  Certainly appreciate your work!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I think I understand your reasoning. I hope the new Iodine (which is written in C) and Plezi (features were removed rather then added) would make scalable and lower level implementations easier.